# How to plot streamline with VTK and C++?

Tags: c++, vtk

I want to visualize streamline in C++ with VTK. I have written a code, but it just shows the edges of cube and the streamline is not visible. Here is my code:

```
vtkPoints *p=vtkPoints::New();
vtkFloatArray *vectors=vtkFloatArray::New();
float vector[3];
vectors->SetNumberOfComponents(3);
int sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
        {
                p->InsertPoint(sum,k+5.0,j+5.0,i+5.0);
                vector[0]=0.5*k+0.1;
                vector[1]=0.2*j+0.2;
                vector[2]=0.3*+0.3;
                vectors->InsertNextTuple(vector);
                sum++;
        }

vtkCellArray *line=vtkCellArray::New();
line->InsertNextCell(2);
line->InsertCellPoint(63);
line->InsertCellPoint(15);

line->InsertNextCell(2);
line->InsertCellPoint(0);
line->InsertCellPoint(3);

line->InsertNextCell(2);
line->InsertCellPoint(0);
line->InsertCellPoint(12);

line->InsertNextCell(2);
line->InsertCellPoint(12);
line->InsertCellPoint(15);

line->InsertNextCell(2);
line->InsertCellPoint(3);
line->InsertCellPoint(15);

line->InsertNextCell(2);
line->InsertCellPoint(0);
line->InsertCellPoint(48);

line->InsertNextCell(2);
line->InsertCellPoint(48);
line->InsertCellPoint(51);

line->InsertNextCell(2);
line->InsertCellPoint(48);
line->InsertCellPoint(60);

line->InsertNextCell(2);
line->InsertCellPoint(63);
line->InsertCellPoint(60);

line->InsertNextCell(2);
line->InsertCellPoint(12);
line->InsertCellPoint(60);

line->InsertNextCell(2);
line->InsertCellPoint(63);
line->InsertCellPoint(51);

line->InsertNextCell(2);
line->InsertCellPoint(51);
line->InsertCellPoint(3);


vtkPolyData *poly=vtkPolyData::New();
poly->SetPoints(p);
poly->SetLines(line);


vtkStructuredGrid *grid=vtkStructuredGrid::New();
grid->SetPoints(p);
grid->GetPointData()->SetVectors(vectors);
vtkRungeKutta4 *integ=vtkRungeKutta4::New();
vtkStreamLine *streamer=vtkStreamLine::New();

streamer->SetInput(grid);
streamer->SetIntegrator(integ);
streamer->SetIntegrationStepLength(0.15);
streamer->SetMaximumPropagationTime(500);
streamer->SetNumberOfThreads(2);
streamer->SetStartPosition(5.0,0,0);
streamer->SetStepLength(2.5);
streamer->SetTerminalSpeed(0);
streamer->SetSpeedScalars(0);
streamer->SetVorticity(0);

vtkTubeFilter *streamTube=vtkTubeFilter::New();
streamTube->SetInput((vtkPolyData *) streamer->GetOutput());
streamTube->SetNumberOfSides(12);
streamTube->SetRadius(0.02);
streamTube->SetUseDefaultNormal(0);

vtkPolyDataMapper *pMap=vtkPolyDataMapper::New();
vtkPolyDataMapper *ppMap=vtkPolyDataMapper::New();

ppMap->SetInput(poly);

pMap->SetInput((vtkPolyData *) streamTube->GetOutput());


vtkActor *pActor=vtkActor::New();
pActor->SetMapper(pMap);

vtkActor *ppActor=vtkActor::New();
ppActor->SetMapper(ppMap);

ppActor->GetProperty()->SetColor(0.3800,0.7000,0.1600);

pActor->GetProperty()->SetColor(0.3800,0.7000,0.1600);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>pRen=vtkRenderer::New();

pRen->AddActor(pActor);
pRen->AddActor(ppActor);
//pRen->AddActor(ppA);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>pRenWin=vtkRenderWindow::New();
pRenWin->AddRenderer(pRen);
vtkRenderWindowInteractor *pIren=vtkRenderWindowInteractor::New();
pIren->SetRenderWindow(pRenWin);
pRen->SetBackground(1,1,1);
pRenWin->SetSize(300,300);
pRenWin->Render();
pRen->ResetCamera();
pIren->Initialize();
pIren->Start();
return 0;
}
```

I do not understand where is wrong. I will appreciate if anyone can give some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few things I spotted:

1. The start position of your `streamer` is outside the domain of your `grid`.
2. You might need to call

   ```
   streamer->Update()
   ```

   before

   ```
   streamTube->SetInput( streamer->GetOutput() )
   ```

   and similarly

   ```
   streamTube->Update()
   ```

   before

   ```
   pMap->SetInput( streamTube->GetOutput() )
   ```

   Note that (in VTK 6.3, atleast) `streamer->GetOutput()` and `streamTube->GetOutput()` both return a vtkPolyData, so you don't need to cast it.
3. You might need to set the dimensions of your `grid`, i.e.

   ```
   grid->SetDimensions(4, 4, 4);
   ```
4. Consider using the vtkOutlineFilter instead of manually creating `poly` and adding `lines` to it:

   ```
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkOutlineFilter> edges = vtkSmartPointer<vtkOutlineFilter>::New();
   edges->SetInputData(grid);
   ppMap->SetInputConnection(edges->GetOutputPort());
   ```
5. If you aren't deleting your objects later, you might want to use vtkSmartPointers everywhere, e.g.:

   ```
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> p = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray> vectors = vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray>::New();
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkRungeKutta4> integ = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRungeKutta4>::New();
   vtkSmartPointer<vtkStreamLine> streamer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkStreamLine>::New();
   ```

   See http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/SmartPointers for more.

Comment: According to your advice,streamline is visible by set the dimensions. Thank you very much!   But for the fourth, I cancel  the poly and lines,using the vtkOutlineFilter. vtkOutlineFilter don't have SetInputData, just SetInput and SetInputConnection. I tried   edges->SetInput(grid), But it didn't work and the edge of cube didn't display. I wonder if you have other solution. By the way, I am using VTK5.10.1.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm not too familiar with VTK 5.10. Perhaps try vtkStructuredGridOutlineFilter? This wiki example might help: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/StructuredGrid/OutlineStructuredGrid